# Confidence interval for Hidden Markov Model (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, parameters, hidden-markov-models

I'm trying to uncover the transition parameters of data of a hidden Markov Model using MATLAB. Using the built in hmmtrain function, I can estimate the parameters quite well (I already know what they are supposed to be as it's simulated data for now), but they are always off by a little. So what I want to do is construct a confidence interval for these parameters.

Now, I've searched the web for this quite a bit and it seems as if this is not easy to do. The 'easiest' solution appears to be bootstrapping, but I personally don't know how to go about and implement something like that in MATLAB, for a model as complex as a HMM. Does anyone have any references I could look at that could help me write a script for this, or does anyone know of a package out there that already has this built in?

Edit: 
The main issue I have is that I wouldn't know how a bootstrap method would tackle the problem of HMM. Isn't the whole idea of HMM that you get a specific sequence from which you learn about the parameters? Wouldn't cutting it up for the purpose of bootstrapping automatically create some errors?